# How to Create a Report Viewer editor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web, report

I need to create a tool that can generate reports.

I am using .Net C# MVC4.

The idea is this:
1 user can create or duplicate a existing Report.

1. It need to select the basic table that will generate the report.
2. The related tables in the database then should show up based on FK.
3. Them it needs to generate a easy option to select what will be the Search fields.
4. There will select what Collumns he want to show on the report.
5. All this info need to be saved on database.

I would like to know if there is already anything on web that already do any of this steps.

Or any guides that can help me to create this.

**Current Development that i have:**

On DB i have 3 tables:

1. This table have the Stored Procedure that is called to join all tables
2. this table have a list of all fields that each table can show on report
3. this table store the current fields to show on report:

   - Name of the Table
   - Name of the Collumn
   - Order in report
   - if it is grouped or not
   - functions so i can use things like Sum(ColA)
   - other confugurable things not so important

So on MVC i need a Controller Action for each Report, so that it control the search fields.
I also have a Config section to config the Table 3 explained above.
Finelly on Database i need a stored procedure, that can filter by the preconfigured fields and then a dynamic select is created. 
Back in MVC there is a custom Method that based on the Table 3, can generate a Excel or Pdf version of the Report. Btw Report use iTextSharp.

**The Problem, I need a way to allow user to create new Reports without the need of developer create new Actions.**

Comment: I tryed to search in foruns and here too. I can only find info about Report like (Crystal reports) and SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services), and found some payed solutions but they are too expensive. I also know that excel can make Dynamic Tables based on Database, but 1st i don't understand much about that, 2nd i would not like to give full DB login to the user. Or having to create special logins to DB.